# Domain and range of $g(x) = \frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$g(x) = \frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}$$

for the domain, I find, $\{x|x\ne 2\}$'

and for the range

$y = \dfrac{3x^2+4}{x-2}$ and when $x=2-\epsilon$, $y \to \dfrac{3(2-\epsilon)^2 + 4}{(2-\epsilon)-2} = \dfrac{K}{-\epsilon} \to -\infty$

When $x = 2+\epsilon$, $y \to \dfrac{3(2+\epsilon)^2+4}{(2+\epsilon)-2} = \dfrac{K}{\epsilon} \to \infty$

Therefore, $\text{ran}(g(x)) = (-\infty, \infty)$

have I done this right or am I missing something? For instance, I thought about the case when $x \to \infty$, but this looks like $y \to 1$ in this case, nothing remarkable. I don't even know if that is what we say when we have an $\frac{\infty^2}{\infty}$....Do we just say that is one? Or do we say that is $\infty$ still?

Comment: It's not a rigorous approach, but I often find it helpful to examine the graph of functions like these to get a better idea of what the range might be (which could help you towards a rigorous answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then you look for $x$ such that
$$\frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}=y.$$
Solve this equation: you get
$$3x^2+4=xy-2y \Rightarrow 3x^2-yx+2y+4=0,$$
which gives 
$$x=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2-24y-48}}{6}. $$
So your equation admits real solutions only if $y^2-24y-48 \geq 0$. But this is $y^2-24y+144-192 = (y-12)^2-192 \geq 0$, i.e. $\lvert y-12 \rvert \geq \sqrt{192}$. It is clear that this is not true for every $y$, since for example $y=0$ does not satisfy the inequality. So the range is not $\mathbb{R}$, but is given by those points $y$ satisfying $\lvert y-12 \rvert \geq \sqrt{192}$.

One more comment on your last observation. If $x \to \infty$ then $$g(x) = \frac{x^2\left(3+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}{x\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)} = \frac{x\left(3+\frac{4}{x^2}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)} \to \frac{\infty \cdot 3}{1}=\infty.$$

Comment: That's really good @Gibbs. Thanks for the technique.I saw something like that the other night on another one of my questions, but the determinant was easier to get out than this one.

Comment: You are welcome. Take a look at the edit too. Essentially you are trying to find the subset of the codomain of $g$ where $g$ is surjective (notice that a function is always surjective onto its image). So it is natural to fix $y$ and look for $x$ such that $y=g(x)$.

Comment: Gee @Gibbs. I would have never thought of that. I have a long way to go I can see. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong. For example, $0$ is not in the range of the function. Here is  a hint for finding the range: consider the range on $(2,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,2)$. On these intervals the function is continuous so it will take all values between two limits. So find the max and the min on these two intervals.

Comment: Oh yes of course, if x = zero, we have a constant and y cannot equal zero.

Comment: Thankyou @KaviRamaMurthy too.

Comment: I saw something like this the other night too. Is this called the Mean Value Theorem. I'm not sure how it works, I would ask some questions about it, however I think I better go and read some more first. Thankyou.

Comment: $3x^2+4=3x^2-12x+12+12x-24+16$, well I don't understand that. I think i'm being a nuisance now. Do not worry, I have made this a favourite and I will come back to it when i'm more advanced. Thankyou @MichaelRozenberg

Answer (score 2):

The domain is $$\mathbb R\setminus\{2\}.$$

Now, let $x>2$.

Thus, by AM-GM
$$\frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}=\frac{3(x-2)^2+12(x-2)+16}{x-2}=3(x-2)+\frac{16}{x-2}+12\geq$$
$$\geq2\sqrt{3(x-2)\cdot\frac{16}{x-2}}+12=12+8\sqrt{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $3(x-2)=\frac{16}{x-2}$ or $x=2+\frac{4}{\sqrt3}.$

Also, let $x<2$.

Thus, by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}=\frac{3(x-2)^2+12(x-2)+16}{x-2}=3(x-2)+\frac{16}{x-2}+12=$$
$$=12-\left(3(2-x)+\frac{16}{2-x}\right)\leq12-2\sqrt{3(2-x)\cdot\frac{16}{2-x}}=12-8\sqrt{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $3(2-x)=\frac{16}{2-x}$ or $x=2-\frac{4}{\sqrt3}$ and since $g$ is a continuous function on any interval of the domain and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=+\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}g(x)=-\infty,$$ we got the following range:
$$\left(-\infty,12-8\sqrt3\right]\cup\left[12+8\sqrt3,+\infty\right).$$
Because $$3x^2+4=3x^2-12x+12+12x-24+16=$$
$$=3(x^2-4x+4)+12(x-2)+16=3(x-2)^2+12(x-2)+16.$$
I used AM-GM:

> For non-negatives $a$ and $b$ we have:
>   $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq\sqrt{ab}.$$
>   The equality occurs for $a=b$.

For $x>2$ we have $a=3(x-2)$ and $b=\frac{16}{x-2}.$

Comment: Hi @MichaelRozenberg fine answer, but it is pretty advanced for me. It has given me the AM-GM to look up, so thankyou for that. Is the first transformation you did part of AM-GM too? $\frac{3x^2+4}{x-2}=\frac{3(x-2)^2+12(x-2)+16}{x-2}$ ? I do not understand how you came to this...

Comment: @Bucephalus I added something. See now.

Comment: Thankyou @MichaelRozenberg that is the part I was missing.

Comment: now that I am home from work, I have looked closer at your addition to your answer and still do not follow what you have done. Please name the concept or process so I can google and learn this if it is too difficult to explain in a few hundred characters.

Comment: @Bucephalus I added again.